# Store checkbox value in cookie in webix

Tags: javascript, cookies, store, webix

I am using webix to show datatable with specific columns. I created a checkboxes for each colum to show/hide the columns. I need this checkbox values to be stored in a cookie, so when the client is refresh the page, the checked checkboxes remain checked/unchecked. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
                    {

                       view: "toolbar",

                        cols: [
                            { view: "checkbox", id: "test1", label: "test1", value:1 },    
                            { view: "checkbox", id: "test2", label: "test2", value: 1 },    
                            { view: "checkbox", id: "test3", label: "test3", value: 1 },    
                            { view: "checkbox", id: "test4", label: "test4", value:1 }
                        ]

                    },
                    {
                        view: "datatable",
                        id:   "table",
                        columns: [
                            { id: "test1", header: ["test1"] },
                            { id: "test2", header: ["test2"] },
                            { id: "test3", header: ["test3"] },
                            { id: "test4", header: ["test4"] },
                        ],
                     }
```

Comment: First, you need to show your code, not only the json data. Do you want to know how you create a cookie, set its value and save? ... or the whole logic and script etc for that form?

Comment: This is a code that handles the view for the checkboxes, and datatables, other code is not relevant. I just need to figure out how to save values on refresh. There is no form, just need to work with id's.

Answer (score 2):

Solved this with webix.storage.local.put() and webix.storage.local.get() functions. I have attache onChange event on checkboxes and with setValues saved the current checkbox settings.